# For loop in swift seems to randomly choose increment

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a for loop that executes animations and then removes them on completion, and I am trying to call another method upon completion. Here is my code:

```
func animateMatch(completion: () -> ()) {
    var movingShape = level.shapeAtColumn(pointsContainingShapeArray[0].Column, row: pointsContainingShapeArray[0].Row)
    let destinationShape = level.shapeAtColumn(pointsContainingShapeArray[0].Column, row: pointsContainingShapeArray[0].Row)

    for everyShape in 1..<pointsContainingShapeArray.count {
        movingShape = level.shapeAtColumn(pointsContainingShapeArray[everyShape].Column, row: pointsContainingShapeArray[everyShape].Row)

        let Duration: NSTimeInterval = 1

        let moveShapes = SKAction.moveTo((destinationShape?.sprite!.position)!,duration: Duration)
        moveShapes.timingMode = .EaseOut

        movingShape?.sprite?.runAction(moveShapes, completion: {
            movingShape?.sprite?.removeFromParent()
            print("Removed shape \(everyShape)")
            if everyShape == pointsContainingShapeArray.count {
                completion()
            }
        })

    }
}
```

Basically the idea is that every shape in the array after the first position moves to the position of the first one and then removes it from the scene. This works fine, but my completion was getting called at random times every time. So finally I added the print statement in there. Here was the output:

```
Removed shape 3
Removed shape 1
Removed shape 4
Removed shape 2
```

At this point I got so frustrated I decided it was time for stack overflow. I can't possibly figure out what's going on here. Thanks for any help!

Here is the code that calls this method:

```
func handleSwipe(move: Move) {
    view.userInteractionEnabled = false

    level.performMove(move)

    scene.animateMove(move) {
        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
        if hasMatch {
            self.view.userInteractionEnabled = false

            self.scene.animateMatch() {
                self.scene.addNewSpritesForShapes(pointsContainingShapeArray)
                hasMatch = false
                self.view!.userInteractionEnabled = true

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: `runAction` is an asynchronous operation. This is behaving as expected. :p

Comment: Any ideas on how I should set this up to work the way I want it to?

Comment: You could use `dispatch_apply` to run the loop and its blocks in sequence. I believe there's a lot of other options: using NSOperations, using callbacks to launch B only once A is finished, etc.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the help.....now I've just gotta go learn what all of those are.... XD

Answer (score 2):

The issue isn't the for loop, it's the asynchronous nature of the run action.

When you call `moveShapes` action, it runs asynchronously before calling the completion back on the original thread. This can happen in any order. You can see this yourself by calling your print synchronously:

```
for everyShape in 1..<pointsContainingShapeArray.count {
    print("Synchronous loop: \(everyShape)")
}
```

I think you'd be better off using a `dispatch_group_t` for your final completion:

```
func animateMatch(completion: () -> ()) {
    var movingShape = level.shapeAtColumn(pointsContainingShapeArray[0].Column, row: pointsContainingShapeArray[0].Row)
    let destinationShape = level.shapeAtColumn(pointsContainingShapeArray[0].Column, row: pointsContainingShapeArray[0].Row)
    // HERE
    let group = dispatch_group_create()
    dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), completion) 
    //
    for everyShape in 1..<pointsContainingShapeArray.count {
        // HERE
        dispatch_group_enter(group)
        //
        movingShape = level.shapeAtColumn(pointsContainingShapeArray[everyShape].Column, row: pointsContainingShapeArray[everyShape].Row)

        let Duration: NSTimeInterval = 1

        let moveShapes = SKAction.moveTo((destinationShape?.sprite!.position)!,duration: Duration)
        moveShapes.timingMode = .EaseOut

        movingShape?.sprite?.runAction(moveShapes, completion: {
            movingShape?.sprite?.removeFromParent()
            print("Removed shape \(everyShape)")
            // HERE
            dispatch_group_leave(group)
            //
        })

    }
}
```

Comment: I edited the answer to show how you might use dispatch groups to get notified when all operations have completed. Note your original code w/ the added `// HERE` marks

Comment: Thanks so much! This is really helpful....however I'm still getting the same result. 2,1,3,4 was printed that time... I apologize if I sound ignorant, I'm still new at this, and I'm sure you can tell by my code, I'm still not very good.

Comment: The completion in this line: `movingShape?.sprite?.runAction(moveShapes, completion: {` will always execute in an undetermined order. We can't specify an order there, but what we can do is use the dispatch_group to make sure we wait for all operations to be completed before calling our overall `completion`.  Another option might be to wait for the completion of that function before starting the next sequence.

Comment: I thought that might be the case, but even knowing that, the function is moving on and calling the function inside the    completion before anything else even happens.

Comment: "the function is moving on and calling the function inside the completion before anything else even happens" - not sure I understand this. My knowledge of SpriteKit is very surface level. If the animations aren't happening, it's possible the issue is elsewhere

Comment: The animations are happening, but before they have even visibly started, that should happen after the completion already finished.

Comment: So you're saying after the second animation should wait for the first animation to complete before starting?

Comment: I added the code that calls the function to my question. The "scene.animateMove(move)" function waits for its completion and then executes what's inside, but after "self.scene.animateMatch()" is called, it just keeps right on going and doesn't wait for the completion. So "self.scene.addNewSpritesForShapes(pointsContainingShapeArray)" gets called too early.